# PHP - Is global using to get a variable for example out of the function localscope and aslo out of the page itself without using require or include?

Tags: php, include, global, require

The example i confront this problem i was listen to a tutorial and the instructor didn't refer to the global he wrote in the function and the inquiry was about the global he wrote inside the function using it to call a $connection variable but he didn't include or require the page that has the variable in it. My question is can global cross all the pages without include or require it ?

```
    function get_pages_for_subject($subject_id){
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pages 
            WHERE subject_id = {$subject_id} 
            ORDER BY position ASC";
    $page_set = mysql_query($query);
    confirm_query($page_set);
    return $page_set;
}
```

Comment: I used a global $connection variable inside a script that I included on EVERY page (header.php for example), inside header.php, I defined global in there. From there, it was useful inside every page because of the inclusion

Comment: As long as you declare a variable in the global scope, it is available with the `global` keyword or the `$GLOBALS` superglobal everywhere else in your script after it's declared.

Answer (score 0):

No you must include the page where this variable is declared

Comment: but in the file where the variable declared there wasn't any require or include and it works !